# wso2carbon 4.1 build from source - requires maven 2 or 3?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to buld wso2carbon 4.1 from source.

I can only find instructions for older versions of carbon.

To build from source, do I need to use maven 2, or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Maven3. In WSO2 Carbon 4, we moved from maven 2 to 3.

Comment: This would be useful in the pom.xml - <prerequisites><maven>3.0.0</maven></prerequisites> - I'll raise a JIRA.